# File and Directory don't exist equivalent in XML syntax

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Is there an equivalent to the following Apache rewrite conditions in the Tuckey XML format:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I've tried several things that I have found suggested in various different places but nothing seems to work, the main one I found was:

```
<condition type="request-filename" operator="notdir"/>
<condition type="request-filename" operator="notfile"/>
```

Thanks.